# Add _ when there is a space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to split a string up. I need to somehow take out white space and replace it with _

So for instance:

> Jiffy Lube

but I want it to return

> Jiffy_lube

Does this require regex? or do I do something like `.split('').join('');`
Im not really sure any help would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Example:

> Dicks Sporting Goods

return:

> Dicks_Sporting_Goods

**THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP! IM SORRY THIS IS A POOR QUESTION. I UNDERSTAND NOW WHY ITS A POOR QUESTION. I WILL STILL MARK ANSWERED THOUGH.**

Comment: You're asking how to replace a character in a string? Why not just take half a minute and search for the answer?

Comment: `.split(" ").join("_")`???

Comment: Im sorry everybody. I did some google search, but I guess I didnt search good enough.. :/ I wont ask so early next time.

Comment: Im also sorry that I was so close to the answer.... lol @Bergi you were right that worked too. Im not sure what I was thinking. Sorry again. I will give the answer to the guy with replace once I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that may sound strange but the easiest way to replace a single character more than once in a string is to use a regular expression.

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g,'_')
```

You could also use `split` and `join` :

```
str = str.split(' ').join('_')
```

but that would be both less direct and slower.

Comment: Thank you! I cant accept answer for another 10mins, but thank you for being so fast! Worked perfectly! Sorry I didnt know about replace.

Comment: For consistency, the last should be `split(/\s/)`.

Comment: replace(/\s/g,'_') worked great. Like I said before thanks for all of your guys's answers!

Answer (score 0):

As you said `str.split(' ').join('_')`

Comment: It might be better to use `split(/\s/)`, to handle other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

```
var mystr = "Dicks Sporting Goods"

alert(mystr.replace(/\s/g,"_"))
// Dicks_Sporting_Goods
```